# Does Linux have anything equivalent to Microsoft .Net other than the Java APIs or .Net for linux

Tags: windows, linux, api

The international manufacturing company that I am working for is considering moving from Windows to Linux. The only reason for this that I am aware of is that the Windows automatic updates occassionaly cause some of their applications to fail. Apparently, they do not know how to turn this off. What other reasons they may have, I do not know (cost, the mobile phone effect?). My question is does Linux or some popular variant of Linux have a development environment equivalent in power and functionality to Microsoft .Net other than what Java offers, the Linux version of .Net (Mono) offers, or running Windows as a virtual machine on Linux?

Comment: ".net for linux"?  Heh.  Mono isn't .net.  It's just largely compatible.

Comment: I don't mind if it is not compatible with .Net, just if it is as powerful as .Net, is as widely supported by device manufacturers as Windows/.Net, and has enough support to be around for 10 or 15 years.

Comment: Device manufacturers don't give a damn about Java, .net, Squeak, or any other such VM.  Nor should they -- the VM isn't what's running the driver.  The underlying OS is.  Unless someone happens to be that one moron trying to write systems-level code in .net.

Comment: Makers of industrial handhelds with interfaces to scanners and RFID readers/writers usually use Windows Mobile as their OS and support CE .Net. Some of them support Linux but I am not sure how well they support the integrated devices on Linux. Do they provide a PHP interface for the scanner? Companies that provide controls for communicating with PLCs provide .Net libraries. Some of them have Linux versions but I am not sure how that works. Are they C++ libraries?

Comment: A PHP interface for a scanner?  I dunno.  It'd be possible, considering you can open a serial port the same way you'd open a file.  You probably wouldn't use PHP for a desktop app.  What's available depends partly on the manufacturer, though...which in all your whining, you never bothered to share.  And yes, in Windows they're typically C++ libraries with interop assemblies for .net.  In Linux, it'd be a little different, but not terribly.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of unclear what you are looking for... a Mono IDE that runs on Linux?

Have you looked at http://monodevelop.com/ ? It's not Visual Studio, but it's really not bad as IDE's go, and I think it's cross-compatible with VS project files. Should be packages available for any major Linux distro -- I know all the Debian based ones have it.

Mono's API is pretty compatible with .NET, though there are differences in some of the supporting libraries. There are apache extensions to do ASP.NET, but they are fiddly to get set up correctly.

It's a usable platform though, and it's possible to write Mono code that's 100% .NET compatible if you stay away from certain assemblies that haven't been ported yet.

Comment: I am just trying to figure out if I want to make the switch and keep this job or quit and stay with .Net which I have some experience with. I think it comes down to whether there is something on Linux that I can eventually be as productive in as I am in Windows. And, then is Windows future threatend by mobile devices and is there another option the industrial device manufacturers will support (mainly, industrial terminals and communications to PLCs).

Comment: If you're worth a damn, you'll be able to pick up any one of the dozen languages in common use in Linux.  Perl, Python, Ruby, PHP, C, C++, Java....i mean, the list goes on.  It's a developer's paradise, really -- you can even change the OS itself if you feel like it.  If you're just a .net programmer, quit now.

Comment: None of the languages you mention offer a fraction of what .Net has. I can't even imagine listing C++ as equivalent to .Net. Java is the only thing close and it's a closed environment.

Comment: Seriously?  Have you ever looked at Java?  Perl's CPAN?  PHP's PEAR?  Ruby's gem stuff?  Anything you want, if it's not already there, you can get it easily.  And i dunno what you consider a "closed environment", but you're coming from .net -- you should be used to closed.  Java is open source, and has been for years.

Comment: Yes, I worked in Java before switching to .Net. I like .Net a lot more. I do not want just anything. I want something that is complete, consistent, and will be around for years to come.

Comment: @Ron Carter You seem to be making the mistake of comparing a shallow knowledge of a new language to an advanced knowledge of your current one and making a judgment from that skewed viewpoint.  Its really easy to do when you're a .Net programmer because there are a lot of people out there in the same position doing the same thing and telling it to everyone who will listen.  I learned on C++ first and use to despise Java until I took the time to learn it better.

Comment: @Ron: No, what you want is ".net, but on Linux".  Mono's close, but won't fit.  And any other platform/language, no matter how complete, is going to have a learning curve that will have you saying "this was so much easier in .net".  Just quit.  With that attitude, you won't be happy outside of your box.

Comment: I should clarify that I started out developing applications in Pascal for DEC PDP-11s. I have developed in Fortran, C, VB, C++ (I greatly prefer C to C++), Java, C#, VB.Net, Javascript, HTML, XML/SOAP and others, on RSX/11, VMS, OS/2, Unix (nothing on Linux, though), and Windows. I do not mind learning something new, or a new way of doing something, just as long as it can do everything I can currently do with .Net. I don't care if I know how to do it with another tool just that there is a way to do it with that tool.

Comment: You've heard of Turing equivalence, right?  Anything that can be done in one can (in one way or another) be done in the others.  That's not to say it'll all be equally easy.  But in a huge number of cases, people have already done the hard part for you.  CPAN is freaking *huge*, full of libraries for stuff you'd never think you need to do til you do.

Comment: I like Java the language. I do not like Java the sandbox or Java the "you organize your code my way or hit the highway." I have used PHP. I cannot imagine using it to write a scanner application on a handheld. I have heard of Pearl but I doubt any of the device manufacturers I work with provide a Pearl interface for their devices. I know what computers can do. I know what types of languages there are to program them in. I am not trying to be controversial. I just wanted to know if there was anything like .Net available for Linux. I do not want to have to rewrite everything .Net already does.

Comment: I just don't like having to do things that have already been done and I do not want to work with a hodge-podge of freely available Linux libraries out there for the finding.

Comment: BTW..."Perl".  Not "Pearl".  No one uses Pearl.  :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought it looked wrong to me when I typed it. I think I spent all of 10 minutes looking at it about 10 years ago.

Comment: Casual Linux users (I don't know about the serious ones) really seem to like it.

Comment: I worked in Java for about a year. I have not created a Java application from scratch but I worked on enhancements to a pollution simulator and an application for spooling out work to other applications over the Internet. I would not say my knowledge of Java is shallow.

Comment: @cHao I think you answered my question. 'Not sure I appreciate the "With that attitude" but you're not far off.

Comment: By "closed environment" I mean you are stuck using the libraries Java provides for the devices Java anticipated that you would need. Most if not all device manufacturers provide a .Net library for controlling their devices. I suppose they could write a Java class library for you to use that communicates with their device provided their device was on a network. I am not sure how well Open Source would work. I'd have to have each manufacturer modify my version of Java to support their device. I am vaguely familiar with Perl, PHP, and Ruby. 'Not sure these are good languages for shopfloor apps.

Comment: If your company is moving everything over to Linux without any thought as to how they're gonna make their hardware work with it, you might want to quit anyway.  Cause it sounds like the company's setting itself up for a colossal failure...and i'm going to bet that's not the only stupid decision they've made.  Who knows how much longer you'll have a job.

Comment: I thought about it over the weekend and came up with several good reasons for their (not my) switching to Linux as long as they know what they are getting into and have the people who know how to do it. I told them months ago that I am not a Linux developer and do not know how you do things in Linux, today (what flavor of Linux, programming language, GUI, database, web server, browser, etc.). Since then, they have said they have someone with Linux experience, but given what I have seen on the Windows side of things, I am a little apprehensive.

Comment: One of the things I did over the past few days is search for recent books on the generic topic of "Linux Programming." Linux programming does not seem to have changed much over the years. Of course, I then did the same for "Windows Programming" and came to about the same conclusion. I have not done job searches on the two, yet, to see what specific skills the industry is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am 9 months late. You may have found your solution. You may look at [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/ironpython/).